# Rails Help! Displaying updated_at field of child table in html.ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parent-child, blogs

I have a blog forum that i'm trying to display the most recent comment datetime. I have it sorted by comment's updated_at, but cannot seem to display it correctly.

This is on my posts index page.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
     **<td class="updatedAt"><%= post.updated_at.strftime("%a %b %d %l:%M %p") %</td>**
       <td><%= link_to post.title.upcase, post %></td>
       <td><%= image_tag "blip.png"%><%= post.comments.count %></td>
       <td class="createdAt"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%a %b %d %l:%M %p") %</td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

In the first table data entry i have tried post.comment.updated_at.strftime(...), nothing i am trying seems to work, but the rest of the code works fine, i just need help accessing the comment's updated_at and displaying it.

**EDIT, the updatedAt class does not work correctly, right now it is displaying the updated_at of the post, not the most recent comment, which is what i want.

Knowledge is appreciated :)

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: a `post` has many comments, so you'd need another loop, the first `each` is for your `@posts` but need another for `post.comments.each do |comment|` and then a subtable of the comment data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this is by using Rails' `touch` method on the Comment's association with a Post.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Basically, having:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, touch: true
end
```

means whenever you save a comment, the `updated_at` of the parent post will be updated. Then you can simply display the post's updated_at as you were doing before.